# Gender-neutral equivalent for "Take it like a man"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, gender-neutral

I'd like to find some gender-neutral equivalents of the phrase

> Take it like a man

I'm not looking only for existing phrases -- any interesting ideas for expressing the sentiment "be tough", without implying that *only* one gender or the other would be tough, are welcome.

Comment: A word that I've heard one group of my younger friends starting to use recently as a colloquial, gender neutral equivalent to "man up" is "fortify". It's a new one to me, though, so I can't attest to how widespread its usage is.

Comment: "Be an adult!".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"**Keep a stiff upper lip"**

> Someone who has a stiff upper lip does not show their feelings when they are upset
> [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stiff-upper-lip)

**"Keep your chin up"**

> to stay cheerful and hopeful during difficult times
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep%20one%27s%20chin%20up)

**"Take one for the team"**

> to agree to do something unpleasant that you do not really want to do, or not have something that you want, in order to help or be kind to other people in a group
> [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-one-for-the-team)

**"Grin and bear it"**

> to accept something bad without complaining
> [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grin-and-bear-it)

**"Suck it up"**

> To put up with something; to deal with something, such as pain or misfortune, without complaining.
> [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_it_up)

**"Roll with the punches"**

> 1] to cope with and survive adversity
> 2] to not allow difficulties or criticism to discourage you or affect you badly
> [[Collins]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/roll-with-the-punches)

***"Nil illegitimi carborundum"***

> A humorous pseudo-Latin expression meant to translate as "don't let the bastards grind you down," meaning do not succumb to the oppressive influence of others.
> [[The Free Dictionary]](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nil+illegitimi+carborundum)

And a personal favorite, especially in the context of this question,

**"Put on your big girl panties"**

> *Pulling up your big girl panties* is more than just moving on or dealing with that particular moment. It’s really about standing up, leaving the junk behind and moving forward. It’s about being strong and audacious and bold.
> [[WeInspireWe.com]](https://www.weinspirewe.com/post/2017/10/25/pull-up-your-big-girl-panties)

Comment: The last one, IMHO, is not exactly gender neutral.

Comment: Definitely not gender neutral (though at least as gender neutral as "cowboy up").  Equally definitely does not "imply that only a man would be tough".

Comment: Great list! I've always seen the "carborundum" phrase start with "_Non_" (not like that would make it any more correct, of course :).

Comment: I think *big girl panties* can be worn by either gender.  Nice one.

Comment: @Kit: Thanks.  I certainly use it in that fashion.  ('s why I compared it to "cowboy up"; both contain a gendered term but need not be used consistently with it.)

Answer (score 15):

The gender neutral form of *man* is *adult* or *grown-up*, so I would suggest:

> Take it like an adult
>
> Take it like a grown-up

These are not as idiomatic and do not really preserve the original force of the statement, but that's how gender neutrality often goes.

Comment: Definitely lacking the same zing, but might serve as insults!

Answer (score 6):

> Harden up
>
> Toughen up
>
> No guts, no glory!

An appropriate equivalent would be like:

> Take it like a champ!

Answer (score 4):

- Take it on the chin!
- Take it like a trooper.

Answer (score 3):

> Cowboy up!

I have heard this expression used by men and women alike, and directed **at** men and women alike.

Answer (score 2):

> Take your medicine

It's a bit old fashioned, but conveys the same meaning.

Also:

> Don't be such a cry baby.

Another idea:

> Take it like a unicorn.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "bite the bullet." Toughness implied, no specific genitalia required.

Answer (score -1):

My favourite:

> **Suck it up, princess**

Not exactly gender-neutral

Comment: I'd say it actually is gender-neutral in this case! Well, sort of, anyway. It works well (and I've often heard it used) on both genders. Bit of a different jab depending on the gender, but same results either way.

Comment: It's used on both genders, but it is emphatically not gender-neutral. When used on a man, the insult comes from comparing him to a woman. The whole concept of this expression is that being called female is an insult. Not a good choice.

Comment: @TRiG, I would say the insult comes from comparing a man to a princess, a particular type of woman, not to women in general.