# Equivalent of "Man up" for a female

Tags: phrase-requests, grammatical-gender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gender-neutral equivalent for “Take it like a man”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/gender-neutral-equivalent-for-take-it-like-a-man)

Does this make sense?  For instance:

> "John, just man up and get on with it".

You can't say this to a female, so what is the appropriate equivalent?

Comment: Related: [Gender neutral equivalent of take it like a man](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/gender-neutral-equivalent-for-take-it-like-a-man)

Comment: Gotta disagree with this close. The two phrases mean completely different things. My answer would not have been a good answer for the "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 3):

I think a politically correct approach is in order:

How about *Bite the bullet ***** and get on with it*.

Where ***** is the lady's *name*, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually heard the term `woman up` used before. Having seen the birth of three of my children, not to mention the crap some other women in my life have had to persevere through, I don't think this phrase is in the least bit ironic.

It even has a good [Urban Dictionary reference](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=woman%20up), and they [sell some swag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/products.php?term=woman%20up&defid=5357932) with that printed on it. Of course its existence in the UD kind of implies it is cheifly used in [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English).

Answer (score 1):

> Harden up, princess

works for females as well as males.

Comment: This phrase strikes me as even more condescending than the OPs version

Comment: @simchona: Yes, it is supposed to be condescending; especially when you consider the usual way in which that phrase is expressed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of formality and familiarity, male-targeted terms can be used cross-gender to convey the same meaning. Since most of these terms are very informal anyway, most have become pretty interchangeable. In such cases they're generally said light-heartedly:

- Grow some stones/grapes/balls/chest hair
- Take it like a man
- Man up

... can all be said to a woman whom you know very well, or in a very informal setting. There are more gender-neutral terms:

- Harden up
- Toughen up
- [Sound off] like you've got a pair (traditionally "of testicles", but this one's actually gone gender-neutral, inferring either testes or ovaries)

... as well as female-targeted terms:

- Woman up
- Get your estrogen on
- Put your big girl panties on
- Exercise your P.O.P